# How to download file in asp.net mvc using FileResult

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

How to download file using FileResult in asp.net mvc.I try this code below, but it showing an error :

> Could not find a part of the path 'E:\SRUTHI\LMS\LMS\TrainingMaterial\Uploads\Task List.xlsx'.

```
[HttpGet]
public FileResult FileDownload(string filename)
{
    if (filename != "")
    {
        string[] Filess = filename.Split('/');
        string file = Server.MapPath(filename);
        //string contentType = "application/image";
        string fileName = Filess[Filess.Count() - 1];
        string contentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fileName);               
        return File(file, contentType, fileName);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Your `filename` probably contain server-side path. You need to use relative path when using `Server.MapPath`.

Comment: This is a *huge* security hole. Anyone can pass `filename=/../../../Web.config` (for example) and attempt to read any file on disk.

Comment: Also, the `File()` method is expecting a *relative path*. You can use `return PhysicalFile()` to use a physical path

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto   can you give an example for relative path which should be used.

Comment: Also no need to pass full absolute directory path like that, just pass the file name. Please provide some snippet where the `filename` parameter value comes from.

Comment: The relative path (or virtual path) is somewhat like `~/Uploads/Task List.xlsx` (`~` indicates site root directory, not physical directory). Your current problem is `Server.MapPath` only accept relative paths.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto  Filename is passed from javascript to the controller function FileDownload

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I just pass only the filename in Server.MapPath

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto when i tried this code above:Index was outside the bounds of the array. error occurs. what to do with this error

Comment: When i try the code above Index was outside the bounds of the array error occurs.

Comment: `string[] Filess = filename.Split('/')` returns empty string array because there's no slash `/` in your path, and attempting to access the indexes with `Filess[Filess.Count() - 1]` will throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException` because the value with given index is not exist. Why using an array if you're only have one filename (just use `return File(file, contentType, filename)`)?